# Elastic Beanstalk: What's making an HTTP GET / to my Elastic Beanstalk services?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got multiple services running on EB. They report on errors, and something/someone is making an GET http request to the path `/`.

I know it comes from an ec2 instance, but it's not an ec2 instance of my account. What is it?

Comment: Could it be your load balancer performing a health check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the load balancer is configured to open a TCP connection on port 80. If the instance acknowledges the connection, it is considered healthy.

You can choose to override this setting by specifying an existing resource in your application. If you specify a path, such as /health, the health check URL is set to HTTP:80/health.

By going to config in elastic beanstalk from aws portal it can be configured
[image]

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html)